# how can I assign numerical values to a mathematical expression containing symbols in a file in python?

Tags: python, variables

I have a saved text file which contains a mathematical expression with symbols, such as, `a**2+2*b+c**4` etc.
I open this file and I assign the content of the file to a variable.
Something like

```
with open('N5.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
```

However, when I substitute numerical values to `a`, `b`, `c` etc. the variable called content does not change. It always gives me the symbolic expression.
I want the variable content having the numerical results. Why is it so hard with Python doing this? in Maple or Matlab I would have done it in one string!

I tried the above Python code but it didn't work

Comment: Show us input file contents. Format code as code. Show us the output and the desired output.

Comment: What have you done to _substitute numerical values to a, b, c_? Please show your code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Instead of making the variable substitution manually you might want to take a look to the library [`sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/index.html#intro-tutorial).

Comment: who creates that file? what are the chances it contains something like `os.system("rm /")`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the python in-built function `eval(string_expression)`

For example:

```py
# write a string expression to a file
with open('expression.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('a**2+2*b+c**4')

# read file to a string
with open('expression.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read()

# assign values to the variables in the expression
a = 5
b = 4
c = 3

# evaluate your string expression
print(eval(content))
# prints 114
```

Reference: [eval() - official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: @nicololopiparo you can consider accepting the answer. It will help others find the correct solution.